# How to find logs for pods created and deleted within a short period of time

Tags: kubernetes

When k8s job keeps recreating pods within 10 seconds, what is the best way to get the related logs and find out the root cause? I tried to use

```
kubectl logs <pod> -n <namespace>
```

and always got ***Error from server (NotFound): pods "XXXX" not found*** as it already got deleted and a new pod got created in the meantime.

Comment: In the `describe` for job - does it say the pod it has completed successfully?

Comment: No. It just said Normal SuccessfulCreate 34s (x56297 over 5d14h) job-controller (combined from similar events): Created pod: XXXX

Answer (score 1):

If the pod "restarting/crashloop" then you can get logs from the `previous` run.

```
kubectl logs -n <namespace> <pod> --previous
```

This will show you the logs of the last run of the pod before it crashed. It is a handy feature in case you want to figure out why the pod crashed in the first place.

For the long term you should consider some logging solution as the pod should be treated as a disposable object and should not rely on this.

One of best tool that I used so far without any issue [Kubernetes Log collection using datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/log/?tab=daemonset)